# LDAP Change/Synchronize Time in Linux

Tags: linux, date, time, ldap, synchronization

Beginner system admin here. We have a Linux server and multiple users running in LDAP (2.4.31)

Is there a way to synchronize the local date/time with all of the users? Because some CMOS batteries are already discharged. Ideally, when the LDAP user logs in, it will automatically change the local date and time.
It's hard to use the `date` command every time I check manually all the users. The date/time is critical to the users since there are log files that were being updated by the local time.

PS:

- Setup is on-premise only
- No internet connection
- Goal is to one client, then all the clients/users will use that `date`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am trying to make sense of your question here. I think it have nothing to do with LDAP and everything to do with time synchronisation but I could be wrong.

The part of your question I struggle to understand is "When the LDAP user logs in, it will automatically change the local date and time". Can you specify where this change occurs? Are the users that connects are on windows or linux?

I think what you need here is to use some network time protocol(NTP) servers to synchronize time across all your machines. there are plenty of public ones available for free (see : https://www.ntppool.org/en/)

on recent linux with systemd, the daemon responsible for syncing the time is `systemd-timesyncd` with its configuration file located at `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` if your clients are using windows, there is a similar process to keep the clock ajusted with NTP.

If I misunderstood your question, please clarify

Comment: Hi! The users are in Linux. The "When the LDAP user logs in, it will automatically change the local date and time" is my ideal scenario. Currently, I can see a systemd folder. But I can only see logind.conf. Can I create the timesyncd.conf for the sync purposes?

Comment: Ps: we can't connect it to time servers since internet connection is not allowed in our setup. Only in premise.

Comment: ah, so the date change was not a current behavior but a wishlist :) For a site that does not have a internal NTP server that is allowed to connect to sync to the outside world, the option is to use a hardware clock that an internal ntp server can sync with. (never used one but I know it exist)


if I was you, I  would : 


1 - enquire about an existing internal NTP server (which can be pushed in the DHCP options)


2 - propose a hardware clock solution


if the company set a requirement of no internet connection, they have to provide an alternative for time synchronisation.

Comment: worst case, you install an ntp server without external sync, not great, but at least all machines would have the same date.